# $\int_0^t f(x) - x dx = f^{[t]}(0) - t - 1$

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems, functional-equations, complex-dynamics

Let $t,x$ be nonnegative reals.

Let $* ^{[k]}$ denote k th iteration.

Find real-analytic $f(x)$ such that

$\int_0^t f(x) - x dx = f^{[t]}(0) - t - 1$

Holds.

We require analytic iterations.
( $ f^{[t]}(0) $ is analytic in $t$ )

By analogue also

$\sum_{x=0}^t g(x) - x = g^{[t]}(0) - t - 1$

Find Such $f(x),g(x)$.

Comment: What is meant by $[t]$ iterations when $[t]$ is not an integer?? Or do you mean by the brackets that we take the floor or the ceiling? In this case what do you mean when you say that $f^{[t]}(0)$ is analytic in $t$?

Comment: H(t) is An analytic function, f(H(t)) = H(t+1) , H(t) = f^[t](0).